# App Center shows nothing but a black screen

Tags: 23.10, app-center

I installed Ubuntu 23.10 today, but the App Center won't display the software information, and it shows just a black screen. I installed it again after using `sudo snap remove snap-store`, but the problem still wasn't solved.

Answer (score 0):

1. Refresh the App Center:

   Close the App Center and run the following commands.

   ```
   killall snap-store
   snap-store
   ```
2. Update the App Center:

   ```
   snap-store --quit
   sudo snap refresh snap-store --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-23.10
   ```

   Leave the App Center open for about half an hour to give it time to download all the software packages' information.
3. Purge and reinstall the App Center:

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade  
   sudo apt purge snap-store
   sudo apt install snap-store
   ```

   `sudo apt purge snap-store` removes App Center and its associated configuration files, and `sudo apt install snap-store` reinstalls them.